# Website functionality disturbed or hacked

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a user messaging system on my website. 
I have a `< button id="msg" data-id="1">` the 
`data-id` corresponds to  `user_ id` column in `users` table . Now i send message to user using ajax jquery and php .
Via jquery i get `data-id` of clicked `.msg` button and send msg to that user using php.

Now my problem is i have restrictions of some people sending message to some other . But those can easily send those messages illegally by changing `data-id` in developers mode.how i can prevent this?

Comment: add server side validation and check for a valid recipient...

Comment: There are lot of ways to accomplish that.. 1.encryption based on user id and ip address as stackoverflow do.. etc..

Comment: But is that not too much processing?
1st validation in main page.
Then again in sending small messages?
Is that what big companies like google ,twitter do? @mark

Comment: Can u expain your methods @rajaprabhu in an answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always use some server side generated hashes sent to the front ends to ensure that the user-id sent back to the server is the one that originally opened the page. There is not even a need to call the database for that.

```
<button id="msg" data-id="1" data-hash="1234abc">
```

where you calculate the hash with a salt/secret and the data-id. And upon submit you just check if the supplied hash is the same like the newly calculated.

so in php you could do something like:

```
$userId = 1;
$secret = 'yourVeryPersonalSecretSentence';
$hash = sha1($secret . $userId); // would create something like "d0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940"
```

in your html you would have:

```
<button id="msg" data-id="1" data-hash="d0be2dc421be4fcd0172e5afceea3970e2f3d940">
```

and upon ajax call, you just double check:

```
$userId = $idValueFromForm;
$secret = 'yourVeryPersonalSecretSentence';
$hash = $hashFromForm;

$newHash = sha1($secret . $userId);
if ($newHash === $hash) { // the userid was the same as sent to the browser
...
}
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Can u give an example ? Sounds interesting.

Comment: a very simple version could be to add a secret string to your id, and calculate an MD5 or SHA1 or whatever hash value. There should be a method for that in the programming language you are using.

Comment: In php i create a `hash` and send it along with `data-id`
but the hacker can also change the `hash`

Comment: Well, since he does not know your secret, he won't be able to create the same hash value, since its very unrealistic to create the same hash value by random.

Comment: How i create a hash value?

Comment: please see the code snippets above (i added them in my answer)

Comment: Is there any way that hash can be decoded?

Comment: No, since its a one way encoding: see also: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function

Comment: Is there any 1) limit on string to be hashed and 2)limit on number of character sent via $.get and $.post request?

Answer (score 4):

You can't stop people from editing the HTML of your site, anything front end can generally be edited.

Regarding restrictions, I am not 100% what you mean however, if user a can't send a message to user b, then you have to do that server side. Return false and display the appropriate message to the user front end.

Comment: But is that not too much processing?
1st validation in main page. Then again processing backend while
sending messages? Is that
what big companies like google ,twitter
do?

Comment: Doing a little validation is not hard on the server at all. I assume Google and Twitter do a lot of things behind closed doors regarding message sending.

Comment: For validation i have to do  say (2-4 queries) 
so doing that will make it slow?

Comment: Totally depends on the queries, I shall refer you to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5203844/how-many-queries-are-too-many

Comment: Queries are simple fething just 1 row from 1 column!

Answer (score 1):

You always have to assume something may go wrong, that people want to hack your site, that thay want to make SQL injection.

You have to double check everything, make even extra validation to make sure your application is safe. At the moment anyone can send messages to all your users creating simple script so it's huge security issue.