# How to store an associative array assigned to smarty template into hidden field and get it back in PHP on form submission?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, post, hidden-field

I've an array titled `$rebate_by_product` in PHP and I've assigned this array to a smarty template as follows:

```
$smarty->assign('preview_data', $rebate_by_product);
```

Following is the content of array `$rebate_by_product`:

```
Array
    (
        [op] => preview
        [id] => 
        [form_submitted] => yes
        [company_id] => 46
        [1] => Array
            (
                [pack] => 10
                [quantity] => 20
                [volume] => 30
                [units] => 5
                [amount] => 40
                [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-01
                [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-08
                [applicable_states] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 2
                        [1] => 6
                        [2] => 14
                    )

                [rebate_total_count] => 5000
                [products] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 10
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [pack] => 50
                [quantity] => 60
                [volume] => 70
                [units] => 12
                [amount] => 80
                [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-09
                [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-15
                [applicable_states] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 7
                        [1] => 12
                        [2] => 17
                    )

                [rebate_total_count] => 10000
                [products] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 9
                    )

            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [pack] => 500
                [quantity] => 1000
                [volume] => 1500
                [units] => 9
                [amount] => 2000
                [rebate_start_date] => 2014-05-21
                [rebate_expiry_date] => 2014-05-31
                [applicable_states] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => 46
                        [1] => 48
                        [2] => 50
                    )

                [rebate_total_count] => 9000
                [products] => Array
                    (
                        [1] => 11
                    )

            )

        [multiselect] => 50
    )
```

Now I want to store this entire array into a hidden field on a form in smarty template. When user submits this for I should get the entire array in `$_POST`. How to achieve this? I tried with following code but it didn't work:

```
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="reb_data" id="reb_data" value="{$preview_data}">
```

After submission of form I'm getting following output if I print `$_POST`.

```
Array
(
[reb_data] => Array
)
```

Actually I want the entire array as `$rebate_by_product` in `$_POST` under key `[reb_data]`.

Comment: however, you decide to send the data (serialized etc.) and reload it later. i normally base64_encode it before sending it and base64_decode when i get it back. That way it is certain to be unchanged by the HTML processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`serialze()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)/[`unserialize()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) exactly for this purpose. The assign would become this:

```
$smarty->assign('preview_data', serialize($rebate_by_product));
```

On the next page, you can get the array back like this:

```
$rebate_by_product = unserialize($_POST['reb_data']);
```

If that was somehow unsuccessful, the function will return `FALSE`.

Comment: It's not working yet. When I submit the form blank page appears. What's going wrong in this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot send arrays as input. What you have to do change format:

```
$smarty->assign('preview_data', htmlentities (json_encode($rebate_by_product),ENT_QUOTES));
```

And after sending form you have to do in PHP:

```
$rebate_by_product = json_decode($_POST['reb_data']);
```

You also need to think what you want to do with this data. You have to assume that user could change it so you cannot be sure data you receive would be the same you assign them before displaying form (you can read about such issues in [Website functionality disturbed or hacked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23471388/website-functionality-disturbed-or-hacked/23471689)  - they are real).

Comment: It's not working yet. When I submit the form blank page appears. What's going wrong in this?

Comment: I've added htmlentities to the code above. Sending should work fine now